# How can I make the underline change color every time the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like the underline under my text to change color randomly every time the page loads.

I have had success using this script before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var classes = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
    var random_class = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];
    var title = document.getElementById('decor');
    classes.forEach((el) => {
    title.classList.remove(el);
    });
    title.classList.add(random_class);
</script>
```

with this on my CSS:

```
.red {
box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 ##FF0000;
}

.yellow {
box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #FFFF00;
}

.blue {
box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #0000FF;
}
```

But I cannot (newb here) rig it with my current code (see snippet below)

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
 display: block;
 width: 85%;
 /*center vertically & horizontally*/
 position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}


a, a:visited, a:hover {
 -ms-text-align-last: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
 text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;

}    


#test1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 7.5vw;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 7.7vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

#test1:before {
    content: "";
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #00f9ff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
    animation-name: stretchRight;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    z-index:-1;
}


@keyframes stretchRight {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="test1"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/dqkgUe8.jpg">hello darkness my old</a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

How can I rig them together to make it so that the underline changes color every time the page loads?

Comment: Use cookies. if the cookie exist with a value of some color (for example, red), display the red and change the value to another one (e.g.: blue), and so on. See more on MDN: [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `.red, .yellow, .blue,.etc...` classes to your `css` and have javascript pick one of those classes and add it dynamically to `test1`. Since the number of colors to choose from is small, the colors might repeat very often. If you want to ensure that the colors are different, you might need to use a cookie to store then value.

```js
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var classes = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow','green','cyan','magenta','orange','black'];
var random_index = getRandomIntInclusive(0, classes.length -1);
var title = document.getElementById('test1');
var random_class= classes[random_index];
title.classList.add(random_class);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 85%;
  /*center vertically & horizontally*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a,
a:visited,
a:hover {
  -ms-text-align-last: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

#test1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 7.5vw;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 7.7vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

#test1:before {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #00f9ff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  animation-name: stretchRight;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.red:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 red !important;
}

.yellow:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 yellow !important;
}

.blue:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 blue !important;
}

.green:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 green !important;
}

.cyan:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 cyan !important;
}

.magenta:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 magenta !important;
}

.orange:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 orange !important;
}

.black:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 black !important;
}

@keyframes stretchRight {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="test1"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/dqkgUe8.jpg">hello darkness my old</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That sort of work, but it does not animate when the color changes.

Comment: the code above gives **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null**

Comment: @3p3ch3 this is because you are placing the code at the top of your page correct? To fix this you need to place the code at the end of you page or call it after the window has loaded. If you place the code at the beginning of the page, it will try to find `test1` and fail because `test1`  hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: fixed with `<script type="text/javascript">
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.floor(max);
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var classes = ['red', 'blue', yellow','green','cyan','magenta','orange','black'];
var random_index = getRandomIntInclusive(0, classes.length);
var title = document.getElementById('test1');
var random_class= classes[random_index];
      title.classList.add(random_class);
    });
  </script>`

Comment: @redongreen you are absolutely correct... I can't think of an easy way to reload the animation off the top of my head. I'll have to get back to it later, hopefully someone will answer before then.

Comment: Your code working fine the problem is in the css all the colors should have the `:before` and the ID before the class or just add `!important` `#test1.orange:before`

Comment: @redongreen got it working thanks to the help of Shibi. I've updated the code above please feel free to give it a try.

Comment: @Shibi as simple as that! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RatHat and Shibi thank you both for the amazing help!